# Is there a way of returning a value in a cell when a code is entered?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking to setup a product sheet that contains barcodes linked to a product name.  I have all my products entered in column A and I will enter the products corresponding barcode in column B

In another sheet which I use as an Inventory, I would then like to be able to scan the barcode into column a but return the product name.

I have found a workaround with a formula but this interrupts some of the Google apps script I already run in the sheet so would be looking for a Google apps script

The code that I am looking for would read something like; 
onEdit()  when barcode is scanned/entered into sheet 1 column a, it looks at sheet 2 column b and returns the corresponding value in that row from sheet 2 column a into sheet 1 column a.

I trust this makes sense, I'm only asking if someone knows of a quick answer for this please?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) to achieve your goal, because a [Simple Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) `onEdit` will not work because of its [Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions) that don't allow to set values into sheets as you would want.

> Script executions and API requests do not cause triggers to run. For
>   example, calling Range.setValue() to edit a cell does not cause the
>   spreadsheet's onEdit trigger to run.

Taking into consideration you already solved the part to pass the barcode values to your sheet, then use this code:

```js
function getItemName(e) {
  // Get the two sheets
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var sheet1 = sheets[0];
  var sheet2 = sheets[1];
  // Get the row and col where the event was triggered
  var range = e.range;
  var col = range.getColumn();
  var row =  range.getRow();
  // If it was in col 1 (A) and row 1, then do something
  if(col === 1 && row === 1){
    // Get the items at the second sheet 
    var items = sheet2.getRange(2, 1, sheet2.getLastRow() - 1, 2).getValues();
    // iterate over them
    for(var i = 0; i < items.length ; i++){
      // if the code is found, set it on the first sheet and exit the loop
      if(items[i][0] === range.getValues()[0][0]){
        sheet1.getRange("B1").setValues([[items[i][1]]]);
        return
      } 
    }
    // if no item found, print this message
    sheet1.getRange("B1").setValues([["No item found"]]);
  }
}
```

Now, for setting up the installable trigger, do the following:

1) Go to your Apps Script project

2) Click Edit->Current project's triggers

3) Click "+ Add Trigger"

4) Select :

- Choose which function to run -> getItemName
- Select event source-> From spreadsheet
- Select event type -> On edit

5) Click Save

Comment: Hello @alberto vielma - thanks for your answer, the way I am passing the values is through data validation 'list from range' then sheet "2" is the range.  At the moment the sheet is only adjusting the values when entered in sheet 1 column a to correspond with how they have been entered in sheet 2 column a (hope that makes sense) - any ideas please?

Comment: Could you provide a dummy data example? Do you mean you would be getting data from A1:D1 like [["A1", "B1", "C1", "D1"]] ?

Comment: Thanks @alberto vielma - please see my staging copy of the sheet from the following link.  I trust this helps to clarify, please feel free to play around with it should you need to! 
   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VZrmAPVWcwJ0dUoII28muijUhe3GX2JLxMZSQXGxR4c/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: @Gav, thank you for providing that spreadsheet, I edited my code, let me know if it works as intended for you now